# selenium tests failing randomly when run in parallel - pytest-django

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

When I run my selenium tests (django StaticLiveServerTestCase tests using selenium webdriver), I get random failures when running my tests in parallel using pytest-xdist.

Sometimes my full test suite will pass, and other times it will not.

There are two tests in my test suite that seem to fail most often. All of my tests load data from a fixture, but these two that fail create new objects to test specific edge cases. After they create the objects, I have my logged in client make a get to the URL for the page under test.

Failure modes:
1) The objects that were created during my two tests sometimes will not show up, and I'll get a NoSuchElementException.
2) The object will show up, but the values will be incorrect (they will render as n/a instead of as a number that I assign at object creation).

I'm new to parallelizing my test builds. My debugging has been fairly rudimentary so far. Any help would be appreciated, whether that be through debugging techniques or otherwise!

Seems like this has something to do with the database transaction i use to manipulate the state of the data before accessing the app with the webdriver, not finishing before the webdriver connection is made. The webdriver reads from the old state of the database.

I just need to figure out how to make sure the old connection is finished.

Comment: Have you tried replicating the exact scenario manually? If you are able to reproduce manually then it is a genuine bug. If you are not able to reproduce manually, then you may have to add some wait time to make your tests imitate an actual user

Comment: Can't replicate manually. I forgot to mention that my tests all pass when run sequentially, but only start to randomly fail when run in parallel.

Comment: So it truly seems like the browser cache is not being cleared between test runs. I can assert that the database state is what I expect it to be, but then data that I added in previous tests is still displaying.

Comment: Try a page refresh before assertions

Comment: This does seem to work sometimes, but sometimes it does not. I have found that adding explicit waits in my tests after I manipulate data in my fixtures seems to reduce the frequency of the issue. I think this has to do with the "write / update / destroy" connection to my database not finishing before my server connection triggers the view that reads data from those same tables...i'm getting the same data from previous tests because it has not finished transacting.